Converse of SLLN in Blackwell's Proof of Wald's Theorem
In an article "Conversation with David Blackwell", Blackwell recalls a proof he wrote in some paper on Wald's theorem:
Suppose $X_1, \ldots $ are iid random variables and $N$ is an independent random variable that is a stopping rule for $X_i$. Call each realization of $N$ as $N_i$.
Denote $S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{N_1} X_i$, and in general $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{N_k} X+i$. Then, we can take the arithmetic mean for:
$$\frac{S_1 + \ldots + S_k}{k} = \left( \frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_{N_1 + \ldots + N_k}}{N_1 + \ldots + N_k} \right) \left( \frac{N_1 + \ldots + N_k}{k} \right)$$
As $k \to \infty$, by the SLLN we have the RHS converging to $E[X]E[N]$.
Therefore, the sequence $(S_1 + \ldots + S_k) \frac{1}{k}$ converges almost everywhere. By the Converse of the strong law of large numbers says that the expected value of each $S_i$ must be finite, and that $\frac{S_1 + \ldots + S_k}{k} \to E[S]$.
In this proof, what is meant by the converse of the strong law of large numbers? I was under the impression that the converse to SLLN doesn't hold, and you can some distribution with infinite expectation as a counterexample. Is this because we converge a.e. and therefore we know each expectation of $S_i$ is finite, and thus we have $E[S_i]$ finite and then apply SLLN?
the paper here he cites a paper by Kolmogorov, which I can't read as I don't speak German.
The argument doesn't technically appear in the paper, but the mention to the SLLN converse does. The argument (with the same mention) comes from this article which is an interview between David Blackwell and Morris Degroot.

I'd have to look things up to say more about the converse to SLLN, but the Cauchy distribution and similar things are not a counterexample. In that case, we neither have finite expected values of the individual random variables nor a finite expected value of the average, so nothing converges to anything. The Cauchy distribution is a fine example to know of when the SLLN does not apply because the expected value diverges. However, a converse to the strong law of large numbers would talk about a scenario when the average does converge almost surely to a constant.
